# Free HQL Editor

Tags: nhibernate

I want to use hibernate query languange. Where can I download the HQL editor?

Answer (score 4):

i think what your after is the [Nhibernate Query Analyser](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/NHibernateQueryAnalyzer)