# up-to-date nhibernate query editor

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I am looking for a up-to-date nhibernate query editor that works with NHibernate 3.0+ . I saw the post [Free HQL Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271457/free-hql-editor) . But that one is tested with NH2.1 . Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

- [NHibernate Workbench](http://www.felicepollano.com/2010/05/19/NHibernateWorkbench.aspx)
- [HQLAddin for Visual Studio](http://hqladdin.codeplex.com/)
- [NHibernate Designer](http://www.devart.com/entitydeveloper/nhibernate-designer.html) - Not free, but has much more features

Btw, HQL didn't change as much recently, so some older editors might work well.